# How to add filters for the removal of noise from a recorded audio file in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, audio, voice-recording

I am making an iPhone app to record and play the human voice back just like *Talking Tom*. Everything works fine, but I am not able to figure out how do I remove the background noise in recorded audio file?

I know the low pass filtering is an option to do so, but I dont know how to code this? Can anyone help me to implement a low pass filter or something else to remove the background noise from a recorded audio file in iOS.

Comment: Hope this'll help you, http://www.vocal.com/mobile/ios-native-libraries/

Comment: Got the solution to your question bro ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't do ios, but there is an example of a low pass filter for accelerometer for the iphone at [Accelerometer Low Pass Filtering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6942626/accelerometer-low-pass-filtering) which you may be able to adapt for your use.

Basically the filtered value at time x = unfiltered value at time x * alpha + filtered value at time x-1 * (1- alpha)

And for the filtered value at time 0 = unfiltered value at time 0 * alpha
(assumes that the unfiltered value at time -1 is 0)

You will need to set the alpha using trial and error. Perhaps somewhere in the range 0.01 to 0.1 might be useful.