# BNO055 ACCELEROMETER READINGS

Tags: accelerometer

I am using BNO055 for tracking position and velocity. I am getting the accelerometer readings from the sensor but the readings are not precise. Though the accelerometer is calibrated I am getting some disturbance in readings. I just placed the sensor on table but it accumulating some values. I am attaching some of my readings so you can check it out.
I am very glad if someone help me. [accelerometer readings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vUey.png)

Answer (score 0):

The readings look rather precise to me. The fluctuations are in the hundredths of a m/s^2. And yes that might add up if you plan on calculating the speed or position of the device but you might add some noise filtering to cancel it out. Check here for a start:
[Accelerometer Low Pass Filtering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6942626/accelerometer-low-pass-filtering)